# Laravel implements Shouldqueue different queue

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, queue

In laravel you can call the ShouldQueue interface like so

```
class ProfileWasCreated extends Event implements ShouldQueue
```

By default this will queue the event on the default queue, but I can't seem to figure out how to queue this event on a different queue with the name email.

Comment: I improved grammar. If you can add your code, it would be simpler for other users to see the issues.

Answer (score 4):

```
$this->onQueue('emails');
```

Add the line above in your constructor for the email class. It would set the queue name. Then you can just use the Mail::send() function and it would queue on the "emails" queue.

Comment: Just out of curiosity, where can I find that in the docs?

Answer (score 0):

You can specify the queue where a job should be sent by calling **onQueue()** on the job object, e.g.:

```
$job = new MyJob();
$job->onQueue('queue_name');
$this->dispatch($job);
```

**onQueue** method is provided by **Queueable** trait - it should be already included in your base **App\Jobs\Job** class by default.

**dispatch()** method is provided by ** DispatchesJobs** trait that you should include in the class that you want to dispatch jobs.

Have a look here for more details on how to use jobs and queues: http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/queues#dispatching-jobs-from-requests

Comment: The thing is that once your implement ShouldQueue there is no dispatch, this all happens somewhere else.

Comment: I've added some more info to the answer - including how to get dispatch() method